# How to include a forward slash in my path?

Tags: php

Im using S3 as my storage, and everything works, however when I specify a path, a forward slash equals a folder. However, I want to be able to use a forward slash inside the folder or file name. How do I do that? My code is:

```
public static function GetS3UploadPath($school_name, $subject)
{
    $class_name = isset($subject->ofClass->id) ? $subject->ofClass->name : '';
    $class = $class_name ? $class_name . ' - ' : '';
    $subject_folder = $subject->year->start_year.'-'.$subject->year->end_year.' - '.$class.$subject->name;

    return $school_name.'/assignments/answers/'.$subject_folder; // here
}
```

The `$subject_folder` cannot have a forward slash, as it will create a folder, instead of it being a part of the folder name.

[image: S3 Folders]

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't really have folders.. So the problem you have is more "how can I tell if a slash belongs to a folder name or a file name", and the answer is - you can't, because they're exactly the same. If you really want slashes, then you'll have to reserve some other character for folder separator, maybe `|` or something:

```
school_name|assignments|answers/by_students|1997-1998/...
```

Alternatively, you could encode slashes with some other sequence of characters, then unencode them when displaying to users.. Something like:

```
school_name/assignments/answers!!by_students/1997-1998!!...
```

Comment: S3 does have folders, as I can see it in my S3 Management Console.

Comment: And the folder separator is forward slash

Comment: Nope, that's just a representation.. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

Comment: check out my edited question, it shows a picture of what I see.

Comment: if it really had folders, you wouldn't have to ask this question :)